# How do we know that we have taken all factors into consideration while deriving Coulomb's Law?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, coulombs-law

It was experimentally deduced that
$$F_e \propto q_1q_2$$
$$F_e \propto \dfrac{1}{R^2}$$
where $F_e$ denotes the electrostatic force between two charged particles with the magnitude of their charges being $q_1$ and $q_2$. The two charged particles are kept apart by a distance of $R$.

Now, from this we can deduce that
$$F_e \propto \dfrac{q_1q_2}{R^2} \implies F_e = K_e\dfrac{q_1q_2}{R^2}$$
$K_e$ is Coulomb's constant here and it is equal to $\dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$ in SI units, where $\epsilon_0$ denotes the permittivity of free space.

Now, how do we know that no factor other than the distance between charges and the magnitude is affecting them? There could be some environmental factor that only has a negligible effect on the electrostatic force but under certain conditions, it might have a large effect on the it under some other conditions and we might just end up ignoring it, right?

Comment: Of course. But why would we include effects for which we have no evidence?

Comment: @Dale Can't it be that the effects are negligible for the most part but under some conditions, they get magnified and we have only made observations in conditions where the effects are negligible?

Comment: Yes. What you've described in your last paragraph is the limitation of a theoretical model. Classical electromagnetism makes inaccurate predictions under certain conditions. This happens with all theories in physics.

Comment: @Charlie Makes me a little uncomfortable. Guess I'll just have to get used to it...

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Obviously yes. That is why I said “of course”. What you say is completely obvious. We cannot ever know what effects may arise in regimes that we have not tested until we test them in those regimes. That is why we keep doing experiments

Comment: @Dale Got it, thanks!

Comment: for example, general relaivity theory does drastic changes  for large energies and masses, but at theenergy  level the Coulomb force is posited from observations  the effect of GR is infinitessimally small.